# Video Capture Device Warning on OpenCV python Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

So i was trying to record footage from my usb webcam but i kept geting the warning ***[ WARN:0] global /tmp/pip-wheel-q9vz0pjg/opencv-contrib-python_40a59bd831de4dd7b8677ff65e12c69e/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (893) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video13): can't open camera by index***. I know the camera works because i was streaming the image to my webserver that is also on the RPi but it wont work with openCV.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

filename = '/home/pi/Documents/rpiwbsrvr/v/video.avi'
fps = 24.0
'''640, 480 - 480p
1280, 720 - 720p
1920, 1080 - 1080p
3840, 2160 - 2160p'''


cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 1280)
cam.set(4, 720)

vid_type = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
vid = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, vid_type, fps, (1280, 720))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    vid.write(frame)

    #cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cam.release()
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hi, i think you you must install package v4l-utils. In Ubuntu/Debian you can use the command:
``    sudo apt-get install v4l-utils    ``
The command above will show all connected camera device with camera index in your system. So you modify camera index in this line code. 
``    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(<camera_index>)    ``
I hope my solution will help you. :D

Comment: that "error" is a warning. if you want to react to it, pass `/dev/video12345` instead of just an index.